# Org Babel ignores `org-plantuml-executable-args`

Tags: org-babel

I cannot make plantuml set the UTF-8 charset, I've set

```
'(org-plantuml-executable-args '("-headless -charset UTF-8"))
```

in the `init.el`, but when I check in the message buffer the command invoked, these options are missing

```
java -jar /path/to/plantuml.jar -tsvg -p < /path/to/org-babel-temp-file > /path/to/file.svg
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Do `C-h v org-plantuml-exec-mode` to see its doc string:

> org-plantuml-exec-mode is a variable defined in ‘ob-plantuml.el’.
>
> Its value is ‘jar’
>
> Method to use for PlantUML diagram generation.
> ‘jar’ means to use java together with the JAR.
> The JAR can be configured via ‘org-plantuml-jar-path’.
>
> ‘plantuml’ means to use the PlantUML executable.
> The executable can be configured via ‘org-plantuml-executable-path’.
> You can also configure extra arguments via ‘org-plantuml-executable-args’.

It is probably set to `jar`, the default, but `org-plantuml-executable-args` only applies when it is set to `plantuml`, i.e. when using the `plantuml` executable.

I looked around a bit to find a `plantuml` executable which must have existed at some point, but AFAICT no longer does. And the `jar` method in `ob-plantuml.el` does not allow for arguments (this is probably an omission that is worth a bug report).

SUGGESTION: I think the easiest thing to do is create your own `plantuml` executable as a shell script and change `org-plantuml-exec-mode` to `plantuml`. Something like this (but note it's *very lightly* tested):

```bash
#! /bin/bash

java -jar /path/to/plantuml.jar "${@}"
```

Put it into some directory, make it executable
and then add something like this to your init file:

```el
(setq org-plantuml-exec-mode 'plantuml)
(setq org-plantuml-executable-path "/path/to/script/above/plantuml")
(setq org-plantuml-executable-args '("-headless" "-charset UTF-8"))
```

Very lightly tested.

Comment: Indeed it's set to `jar`, but there's no option to pass arguments in java mode. If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: Added a suggestion to the answer.

Comment: I'll try to open an issue on its mailing list.

Comment: You should try my suggestion: it should work as described.